# Var not getting set using Googles latlng API.

Tags: javascript

I have looked up answers on stackoverflow but can't seem to get it to work. This snippet of code does not set the var 'pos' to anything:

```
var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();
var pos = geocoder.geocode({'address': getCookie('banner-location')}, function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         return {lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()};
     } else {
         return {lat: 0, lng: 0};
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely familiar with the Google Maps API but from a quick glance from this [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) page it seems that you would need to set the `pos` variable within the `geocode` response callback function. The response callback function's return will not be `geocode's` return value. The following may help you out:

```
var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();
// Create pos beforehand to use in the callback to retrieve the data
var pos = null;
geocoder.geocode({'address': getCookie('banner-location')}, function(results, status) {
    // Check the status and set the pos variable here
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        pos = {lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()};
    } else {
        pos = {lat: 0, lng: 0};
    }
});
```

Above I'm setting your `pos` variable within the `geocode` response callback.